# Composer's autloader can't find app class. Why?

Tags: php, autoload, composer-php

I have the following file structure:

```
src/Models/Entity.php 
vendor/*
index.php
composer.*
```

Entity.php contains

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\App\Models;

class Entity {}
```

index.php contains

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\App;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Vendor\App\Models\Entity;

$entity = new Entity();
```

composer.json contains:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Vendor\\App\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php contains

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Vendor\\App\\' => $baseDir . '/src/',
);
```

And I get `127.0.0.1:37409 [500]: / - Class 'Vendor\App\Models\Entity' not found in ...`.

Where is error? What format is for complex namespaces and/or source dir in composer.json?

**Updated**: I was found workaround (move src/Models to src/Vendor/App/Models) but is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Composer/PSR-0 autoloading conventions are pretty confusing. I have to look it up every time I create a new Packagist project.

When you create a composer.json file and set up the autoload info, like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Vendor\\App\\": "src/" }
    }
}
```

what you're saying is "there is a "Vendor\App" namespace that can be found in `project_root/src`. The confusing part is that each nested namespace that you assign to that folder (in this case, 'src') expects to be represented by another nested folder within.

That's why you need to have your class located in `project_root/src/Vendor/App` in order to be found by this autoload scheme.

**Sidenote:** if you happen to use any underscores in your class names, that can also lead to problems with how this works, because underscores also imply a nested folder (ie `App\Models\Type\Entity`, which points to `src/App/Models/Type/Entity.php`, is viewed the same as `App/Models/Type_Entity.php`). So be careful with underscores!

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure this out for an hour, the docs (IMO, for what it's worth) aren't nearly clear enough.